# comprehensive csh to bash translation

Tags: bash, csh

Is there a comprehensive dictionary to translate csh -> bash?   I find many questions and answers which give piecemeal answers, but I'd like a comprehensive dictionary.   I do understand that word for word translation isn't always possible, so that a bit of rewriting may be needed.   Still, the straightforward bits should be quick and easy, and the issues discussed.

For example, it should say that

if ...
endif

is to be translated to

if ...
fi

and discuss the role of newlines.

I am not looking for an automatic translation.

Comment: Welcome U.SE Robert. Not the answer you'd expect, but interesting and related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339775/23889

Comment: Use the keyword `rosetta` in your searches for csh and bash to find various equivalence tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like **[this (https://joelinoff.com/blog/?page_id=235)](https://joelinoff.com/blog/?page_id=235)**.

That references **[bash](/questions/tagged/bash)** and **[tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh)**, but tcsh is intended to be a "fix" of **[csh](/questions/tagged/csh)**, so most of that may still be directly applicable.